# Returning each object in an 'each.do' array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

The title may not have described my question properly, I wasn't sure how to explain what I'm doing without visuals.

I have a set of snags, each snag is connected to a plot *(a plot has many snags)*. Each plot is linked to a development *(a development has many plots)*. Each development is linked to a user *(a user has many developments)*.

I want to return a list of snags that are relevant to each developer.

I currently have the following in my snags controller:

```
def index
  @developments = Development.accessible_by(current_ability)
                             .where(enable_snagging: true)
  @developments.each do |development|
    @plots = development.plots
    get_snags(@plots)
  end
end

private

def get_snags(plots)
  plots.each do |plot|
    @plot_snags = Snag.where(plot_id: plot.id)
  end
end
```

And in my view:

```
<table class="record-list snags">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><%= sortable(@snags, :id) %></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @snags.each do |snag| %>
    <tr data-snag="<%= snag.id %>">
      <td><%= snag.id %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I initially had @snags in place of @plot_snags in the controller, but of course that only returned the last snag / set of snags, rather than all of them.

If I try to create and return a @snags array and add each object in @plot_snags to it (or any other variation of declaring @snags as an array), I get:

```
undefined method `human_attribute_name' for #<Array:0x007ff5334861d0>
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

*UPDATE*

Having looked at it with fresh eyes again today - I couldn't figure out why my join table isn't populating, I will have a look into it again today to get things working 'properly' - it turns out the error I was getting was due to the Sortable interface I was trying to implement in the view. Once I removed the Sortable I was able to populate my snags array and I get the output I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

When you do an each loop inside the controller you end up with the last value asumed by the variable `@some_variable_inside_the_loop`. That value is what you get in the view.

There are many ways to solve the problem, for example using joins: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

This is **very basic option**, moving loop in the view as nested loop.

**Models about:**

```
development has_many :plots
plot has_many :snags
```

**Controller:**

```
def index
  @developments = Development.accessible_by(current_ability).where(enable_snagging: true)
end
```

**View** (let's suppose each model has a `title` attribute, but do whatever you need):

```
<% @developments.each do |development| %>
  <%= development.title %>
  <% development.plots.each do |plot| %>
    <%= plot.title %>
    <% plot.snags.each do |snag| %>
      <%= snag.title %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the plot_snags in a single query. And iterate the @plot_snags variable in the view.

```
private

def get_snags(plots)
  plot_ids = plots.pluck(:id)   
  @plot_snags = Snag.where(plot_id: plot_ids)
end
```

Comment: This performs two queries since you are using pluck which is not needed. Just pass the scope `Snag.where(plot_id: plots)`.